# Problems with Adobe Flash Player and Software Center

Tags: software-center, flash

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit). I manually installed Adoble Flash Player 9 from the software center. The problem now is that the system is not running as it used to. Whenever I click on "software center" the screen goes blank and the start menu does not even let me find programmes. For example, the terminal cannot be found and I can only find it with the hotkeys. No other programmes are to be found.

How could I completely remove Adobe Flash Player? Would that be the solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any package from the command line with

```
sudo apt-get remove [package name...]
```

Bash even completes the package names for you, when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. :-]

However, I don't think Adobe Flash has any influence on the Software Center. There seems to be another problem.

Also, Flash v9 is incredibly old and insecure. Use Flash 11 from the repositories instead.